# Pencil icon in editing rows in an interactive report using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Anyone here know how to make the pencil icon appear in each rows of a table in apex oracle?
I watch some tutorials but their application seems to work perfectly fine but i cannot figure out my problems

Help me to add the pencil icon

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

##### Interactive Report "Link Column"

Go to the "Attributes" Tab for the IR, configure the "Link Column" attribute. This will populate the link item by default.
[image]

Result:

[image]

This solution uses an image, not a icon. You can replace this with another icon - see below.

##### IR: An icon on any other link column

To generate the html, go to the "Universal Theme" [application](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/icons) that is publicly available. Search for the icon you want, click on it, adjust the setttings and copy the html. For example, I took the "fa-edit" icon with default settings:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-edit"></span>
```

Now I defined the column as a "link" and then the html above can be used as value in the "Link Attributes" setting
[image]

Result:

[image]

##### IR: An icon on any other non-link column

An icon can also be placed in a normal column. In that case put the icon markup in the "HTML Expression" setting.